# How to deleting Entries from Reducer / how to return a new state? (React / Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My reducer by default returns this (it's from a tutorial):

```
return [
        {
            id: 1,
            first: "Bucky",
            last: "Roberts",
            age: 71,
            description: "Bucky is a React developer and YouTuber",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            first: "Joby",
            last: "Wasilenko",
            age: 27,
            description: "Joby loves the Packers, cheese, and turtles.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/52xRlm8.png"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            first: "Madison",
            last: "Williams",
            age: 24,
            description: "Madi likes her dog but it is really annoying.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/4EMtxHB.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

I now want to be able to delete user entries from this 'list'. So I went ahead and built a delete user action creator etc., so in addition to the above data, there is now this code preceding it:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_DELETED':
        console.log("Hello from reducer-users");
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state, );
        // console.log(newState == state);
        // console.log(newState.users == state.users)
        // delete newState.users;
        return newState;
        break;
}
```

The idea is that if someone clicks 'DELETE USER', this function is called and a new state is returned with the appropriate user deleted. It also works in the sense that the function is being called (the console.log is displayed). However, I am not sure how to go about deleting a user from this list now? I understand that I need to copy the current state and then delete the user from the copy, & then return the copy so it becomes the new state. Is this correct? If so, I do not know how exactly to dothis. If I try to execute what I have written above, which was just something s.b. on stackoverflow wrote, I get an error:

> user-list.js?1cc2:11 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.users.map is not a
>   function(…)renderList @ user-list.js?1cc2:11render @
>   ?d41d:33(anonymous function) @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:793measureLifeCyclePerf @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:74_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
>   @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:792_renderValidatedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:819_updateRenderedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:743_performComponentUpdate @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:721updateComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:642receiveComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:544receiveComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:126_updateRenderedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:751_performComponentUpdate @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:721updateComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:642performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:558performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:158runBatchedUpdates @
>   ReactUpdates.js?ce09:151perform @ Transaction.js?6dff:138perform @
>   Transaction.js?6dff:138perform @
>   ReactUpdates.js?ce09:90flushBatchedUpdates @
>   ReactUpdates.js?ce09:173closeAll @ Transaction.js?6dff:204perform @
>   Transaction.js?6dff:151batchedUpdates @
>   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js?ef70:63batchedUpdates @
>   ReactUpdates.js?ce09:98dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js?2365:150

This is the whole reducers file:

```
/*
 * The users reducer will always return an array of users no matter what
 * You need to return something, so if there are no users then just return an empty array
 * */
export default function (state = null, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'USER_DELETED':
            console.log("Hello from reducer-users");

            //let newState = Object.assign([{}], state);
            // return newState;

            return state.filter(user => user.id !== action.userIdToDelete);
            console.log("UNTIL HERE");
            // console.log(newState.users == state.users)
            // delete newState.users;
            // return ([{
            //     id: 5,
            //     first: "Bucky",
            //     last: "Roberts",
            //     age: 71,
            //     description: "Bucky is a React developer and YouTuber",
            //     thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg"
            // }]);
            break;
            console.log("UNTIL HERE2222");
    }
    return [
        {
            id: 1,
            first: "Bucky",
            last: "Roberts",
            age: 71,
            description: "Bucky is a React developer and YouTuber",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            first: "Joby",
            last: "Wasilenko",
            age: 27,
            description: "Joby loves the Packers, cheese, and turtles.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/52xRlm8.png"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            first: "Madison",
            last: "Williams",
            age: 24,
            description: "Madi likes her dog but it is really annoying.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/4EMtxHB.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Totally unrelated, but the action name seems wrong-there "-ed" at the end implies past tense, which isn't what's happening. This action is what *causes* a user to be deleted, *after* which a "user deleted" action could be fired.

Comment: thanks, if it's better practice to keep it present tense, i will go ahead and change this. thank you.

Comment: It's just basic grammar, e.g., "DELETE_USER" then "USER_DELETED". It's not a big deal, just pointing it out.

Comment: I understood that. I am just really happy that you point that out, as I want to develop good coding habits

Comment: Naming is hard: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html, http://www.slideshare.net/pirhilton/how-to-name-things-the-hardest-problem-in-programming

Comment: Thanks. I named it in the past tense btw because I thought it would make more sense if I have a look at the log later and see what exactly has happened there etc. But you're of course right that it's misleading, as nothing has been deleted when the action gets called, so I will change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct in saying that your reducer should return a new copy of the state, without mutating the current one. This approach have a few very nice benefits (see here: http://redux.js.org/docs/Glossary.html#reducer)

Assuming the state managed by this reducer is an array, to delete a user from your list, you can do the following:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_DELETED':
        return state.filter(user => user.id !== action.userIdToDelete);
}
```

The key point is that Array.filter returns a new array applying the callback to each element, deciding which one to keep/filter, it doesn't mutate the original array. Check out the docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

You could be tempted to use Array.splice instead (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) but that would be wrong in this case, since `splice` "changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.", so it does mutate the original one.

Note that you need to pass `userIdToDelete` in your action payload.

Also, you don't need `break` as you're already using `return`.

As for the exact reason to the error you posted, the problem is that at the moment your reducer is returning an object instead of an array: `let newState = Object.assign({}, state, );`  Then, somewhere in your components you're reading from the state and you're trying to call `map` on your state, which is not an array anymore (hence no `map` method defined for `this.props.users`

**Another suggestion:**

I'd really recommend you to start using plain Js inside your reducers, always being careful about methods that mutate objects in place. 
After you know what you're doing, sometimes in Js working with immutable data structures can be clumsy, so you can start looking into using these libraries to ease the pain for more complicated scenarios (but only if you really need), ordered by complexity (obviously in my opinion):

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html
- https://github.com/substantial/updeep
- https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: amazing, thanks a lot. i have added the following to my action, and it seems to work: `userIdToDelete: user.id` - just checking again now whether this is good practice? thanks for all the additional advice as well!

Comment: Yeah that's the way to do it. You normally pass some arguments to your action creator function (I'm assuming you're passing your user object) and add some properties to your action object (```type``` is the only real mandatory thing in there, everything else is up to you really, as long as your action is a plain object and json-serialisable)

Comment: one more question: does `state.filter(user => user.id !== action.userIdToDelete);` really delete the user permanently or just filter the view for me? when i click on the user names (I did not post this above), the 'deleted' user re-appears again

Comment: I think this is because I hardcoded the users in the reducer-users file, so they will get returned whenever the action is not USER_DELETED (see code above). How would I change this so that I can permanently delete users? I guess I will have to put them somewhere else from where they are now, I'm just not sure where

Comment: Yes, given that you are doing the right thing and that you don't have the same user stored somewhere else in your state. "permanently" in this context means "from memory". If you refresh the page, the user would still be there.

Comment: Yes, that can be the case. If you post your reducer code I can have a look.

Comment: it's not because of a refresh of the page, it's still within the lifecycle of my app. i think it's because my users reducer just return all of them by default anyways. i just don't know now how to put them somewhere else so that they do not get returned again by my default return function

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/fabiosussetto/7tu5zjf0/  I'd suggest reading how switch case works in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: I guess I need to find a way to define an initial state and then just return 'state'. I did this now by checking in my reducer whether state==null, and if so, populate it with stuff. then later i just return 'state'. but there might be a much better way to do this, I will open up a new topic for this, so I won't spam everything into this thread here

Comment: If you look at the url i my previous comment you'll see an example